# Excel writer Pandas not working on Heroku Deployment

Tags: python, heroku

Hi I am facing a problem with flask and heroku. My web app has a function to write an excel file to the current working directory of the admin. Locally it is writing the excel file correctly into my directory. Bu when I have deployed to Heroku, it is not writing the excel file anywhere? Is there a solution?

The function which is performing this action:

```
def savefileas(df):
    
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("reports.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter')
    file=df.to_excel(writer)
   
    writer.save()
    flash("The excel file has been saved to your working directory",'success')
```

Comment: Add `os.getcwd()` to the output message to see where the file is being written.

Comment: You can try to use ./reports.xlsx in the pd.ExcelWrite function

Comment: I printed out os.getcwd. The path is saying /app but I think it is saving it in some heroku folder or something but I want to save it in the specific users local directoy on their machine. How to do this?

Comment: @MananPyJava i tried using ./reports.xlsx. It is obviously saving the file somewhere but not locally I think it might be saving it in some external heroku location or something but I dont want that. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: If you try to read the same file from the code, is it able to read it?

Comment: @Manan Java What do you mean read the same file? My function involves queryind data from the database and writing the dataframe into an excel file

Comment: Locally , my code is working perfectly. only on heroku it is giving a problem.

Comment: @anish ya, just make an api endpoint to display some data by reading the file. You may delete the endpoint afterwards. Just need to see if the file is present or not. :)

Comment: So basically in my function definition, after writing the excel file I also write pandad.read_excel and check whether the data is printing correctyl right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234090/discussion-between-anish-and-mananpyjava).

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku applications have their own backend filesystem, which I doubt you can access.

You'd need to write your file to an external file store if you're expecting to get access to it, however using a database would make more sense than a excel file

> I want to save it in the specific users local directoy on their machine

Then you need to make your Flask response be a file octet stream

https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/utils/#werkzeug.utils.send_file